# How to setup sockets for a web-based terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, node-red, xtermjs

I'm currently working on a project and want to implement a web-based terminal in the node-red-dashboard. I've already set up xterm and wetty. The problem I got is my small knowledge about sockets. Currently I'm trying to link wetty with xterm but it wont work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/xterm/css/xterm.css" />
<script src="/xterm/lib/xterm.js"></script>
<script src="/xterm-addon-attach/lib/xterm-addon-attach.js"></script>
<div id="terminal"></div>
<script>
    const socketio = context.global.get("socket.io");
        //const sockett = new nett.Socket('3001');
    const socket1 = io("ws://localhost:3001");
    var term = new Terminal();
    var attachAddon = new AttachAddon(socket1);
    term.loadAddon(attachAddon);
    term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
    term.write('Raspberry $ ');
</script>
```

Wetty is hosted on port 3001 and I want to link it to a node at the same machine.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just saying "it won't work" doesn't really help us. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73633418/edit) the question to explain what if any errors are shown in the browser developer console.

Comment: @hardillb No errors etc.. Would have told you if that was the case. When im trying to attach the terminal even xterm isnt getting displayed. Instead of moaning you could tell me something about my syntax. As I asked: Can you see anything that seems to be wrong in the code snipped?

Comment: The comments are to help you [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) your question to make is easier for others to help you. Are you sure there are no errors, even in the `network` tab? Do you see the browser trying to make the connection to localhost:3001 or actually loading the `xterm` resources? Also a clear description of where you have put that code will help, I assume it's in a Node-RED Dasboard Template node, but that is not clear from the question.

Comment: @hardillb Oh yes, your right its in a Node-RED Dashboard Template node. Looked again for errors and now I'm getting: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'socketio' has already been declared". I guess I have to clean up and close the socket somehow? In the network tab I can see its calling the attachAddon but it doesnt seems like its trying to make any connection to localhost:3001

Comment: The only wetty I am aware of brings server and frontend as ready-to-go solution. If you mean the same wetty - maybe try not to rip it apart (as it might be opionated for paths etc.) - instead use its iframe feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the context from within a NR Dashboard template node like that, because it's running in the browser not the NR backend.

And since the NR Dashboard already uses Socket.IO there should be no need to try and load it again.

Delete the following line:

```
const socketio = context.global.get("socket.io");
```

Comment: Ohh perfect I think we are coming to an end. Now I got a new error: "GET http://localhost:3001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OCO205O net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: I've tried to set `const socket1 = io()` but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you sure wetty is expecting a socker.io connection and not just a basic websocket connection. They are not the same thing...

Comment: No, I'm not.. Is there maybe a workaround or is it possible to set up a websocket?

Comment: I tried to create a Websocket but just got `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3001/' failed`

Comment: Which suggests the problem might be on the other end...

Comment: What do you want to tell me? It's not possible what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I've checked the network traffic and it seems like wetty is communicating over socket.io